# Cannot get data from table of WordPress MYSQL

Tags: php, wordpress

I got a table called `newdata` and there is a column called `name`. I'm trying to get the value of `name` where the ID is `1` with the following code:

```
<?PHP
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'newdata';
$results = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT name FROM $table_name WHERE id = 1"));
?>
```

But the error shows:

> Undefined variable: wpdb`and`Trying to get property 'prefix' of non-object

and

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query()`.

Anything I do wrong?

**Edited:** I don't need to define the wpdb like `global $wpdb;` because it's not within a function.

Comment: Where is `$wpdb` defined? You might not need the `global` but a variable needs to be defined to use it. It could be defined higher in context but needs to exist. PHP is more relevant here than `mysql`.

Comment: @user3783243 Do you mean define the wpdb like `$wpdb;`? Already tried but doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: You need `$wpdb =` somewhere and from your usage I presume that should be a database connection to your wordpress db. Is this being called in a wordpress project? Likely https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55625/how-to-initialize-wpdb is relevant here

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use WordPress variable without context, where `$wpdb` is defined? You haven't defined it in your script, nor used WordPress init procedure.

Comment: Edited the code and I don't understand what's the use case of the init procedure and how it helps in this case. Your answer just pointed out the possible problem without reference, example, and answer.